# How to create UIActionSheet or UIAlertController(UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet) like Apple Music?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet, uialertcontroller

In my app, I want to create a `UIActionSheet`or `UIAlertController (UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet)` like Apple Music.

I want to show user profile picture and some basic details of user in first row of `UIActionSheet` and other option like normal `UIActionSheet`.

[image: Apple Music] [image: My Requiremnt]

Comment: Okay, what have you tried to achieve that goal? Please show your current setup where you try to present the customized view with all the data that you want to show.

Comment: As of right now what I'm doing is custom UIViewControllers in which I've set up delegates and stuff. There are no hints on the current Apple SDK as to how they're doing this

Answer (score 0):

In somewhat I can give you the sample coding for your question

```
UIAlertController *alertMusicVideos =   [UIAlertController
                             alertControllerWithTitle:@"Music Videos"
                             message:nil
                             preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

UIAlertAction *actionAddProfilePhoto = [UIAlertAction
                     actionWithTitle:@""
                     style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                     {
                         //Do Whatever you want to do here 
                         [alertMusicVideos dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                     }];

UIAlertAction *actionPlayNext = [UIAlertAction
                     actionWithTitle:@"Play Next"
                     style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                     {
                         //Do some thing here
                         [alertMusicVideos dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                     }];
UIAlertAction *actionAddToUpNext = [UIAlertAction
                         actionWithTitle:@"Add to Up Next"
                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                         handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                         {
                             //Do Whatever you want to do here when click this button
                             [alertMusicVideos dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                         }];
UIAlertAction *actionAddToPlayList = [UIAlertAction
                         actionWithTitle:@"Add To PlayList"
                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                         handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                         {
                              //Do Whatever you want to do here when click this button
                             [alertMusicVideos dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                         }];
UIAlertAction *actionDeleteFromMyMusic = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:@"Delete From My Music"
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                               {
                                    //Do Whatever you want to do here when click this button
                                   [alertMusicVideos dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                               }];

 UIAlertAction *actionCancel = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                               {
                                    //Do Whatever you want to do here when click this button
                                   [alertMusicVideos dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                               }];

[actionAddProfilePhoto setValue:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourProfile.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] forKey:@"image"];

[alertMusicVideos addAction:actionAddProfilePhoto];
[alertMusicVideos addAction:actionPlayNext];
[alertMusicVideos addAction:actionAddToUpNext];
[alertMusicVideos addAction:actionAddToPlayList];
[alertMusicVideos addAction:actionDeleteFromMyMusic];
[alertMusicVideos addAction:actionCancel];

[self presentViewController:alertMusicVideos animated:YES completion:nil];
```